Why does xarray.groupby with Dask-backed datasets fail on large data?
I'm working with a large Dask-backed Xarray dataset loaded from a Zarr store. The dataset has dimensions along a dim1 axis and includes a coordinate (group_key) and a data variable (data_var). Both the coordinate and the data variable are perfectly chunked and aligned.
Here’s a simplified view of the dataset:
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:      (dim1: 58305782, dim2: 8)
Coordinates:
    group_key    (dim1) <U20 dask.array<chunksize=(100000,), meta=np.ndarray>
  * dim2         (dim2) <U22
Data variables:
    data_var     (dim1, dim2) uint16 dask.array<chunksize=(100000, 8), meta=np.ndarray>

I want to group and sum the data_var variable by the group_key coordinate. The group_key contains non-overlapping labels that are grouped together and adjacent. For example, rows with the same group_key label (e.g., group1, group2, etc.) are already contiguous in the dataset.
def group_and_sum_by_key(ds):
    grouped = ds["data_var"].groupby("group_key").sum()
    return grouped.compute()

However, this code breaks on large datasets. I think it fails during the group by operation, and I only see killed in the terminal, but mprof shows memory maxes out. In this example the group_key contains
However, this code breaks on large datasets. I think the failure happens during the groupby operation itself, not the sum. The terminal shows killed, and memory profiling (mprof) suggests that memory usage maxes out.
I expected Dask to handle this efficiently by processing chunks incrementally. Is there something about xarray.groupby or Dask-backed datasets that makes this approach unsuitable for large-scale data? What’s the recommended way to perform groupby operations with Dask-backed Xarray datasets on very large data, especially when the group_key labels are already grouped and contiguous?

GroupBy will gather all data of the same group into a single partition, will it fit in memory in your case?
